# How to speed up c++ eigen decomposition

Tags: matlab, pca, eigenvector, intel-mkl

I use the `MATLAB` to do eigenvalue decomposition, and the dimension of data is about `10000`, so the covariance matrix is `10000*10000`. When I use the `eig()` function in MATLAB, it is very slow. Is there any way to speed up the eigenvalue decomposition.
I use the eigenvalue decomposition to do principal component analysis(PCA), so I just use the top K eigenvalues and eigenvectors. There is no need to get all the eigenvalues and eigenvectors. I have tried to use the `Intel-MKL` to do eigen decomposition, but when I use the `mex` interface, there are some errors. I posted it in the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19220271/how-to-use-intel-mkl-for-speed-my-own-matlab-mex-cpp-applications

Please give me some advice, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`eigs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eigs.html) if your data is sparse, or if you are interested in the first `k` values. For example, 
`eigs(A,k)` returns the k largest magnitude eigenvalues. Note that `eigs` will be faster only for the first few eigen-values, and will be slower for k > some value (probably 5...)

Comment: Ok, Thanks. But I want to use c++, because MATLAB is non free.

Comment: MKL is not free either, for both research and commercial purposes.

Comment: Then, do I need write the `eig` function by myself? I know some open source libraries for these computation, such as OpenBLAS, LAPACK, etc. But they have no invokable `eig` function.

Comment: LAPACK definetely has routines for eigenvalues and eigenvectors (or check Armadillo library to get more C++-like interface). You can use GNU Octave also

Comment: @nathan - `eigs(A,k)` is not only less accurate than `eig(A)` but also slower. Test it and see for yourself.

Comment: Of course `eigs` will be less accurate, but if are only interested in the first 2-3 eigen values, I disagree for it being slower. More than that, sure, but that's what I tried to say in the answer. Since that wasn't delivered I'll edit the answer to make clear.